# Question about the exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry

For $v \in \mathcal{E}_p$ and $p \in M$, define $\exp_p(v) = \gamma_v(1)$, where $\gamma_v$ is maximal geodesic with initial point $p$ and velocity $v$. My textbook says that:

$$\exp_p(tv) = \gamma_{tv}(1) = \gamma_v(t)$$

I am confused about the last equality, and would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: From a physicist point of view: following a path during a time $t$ with velocity $v$ brings you to the same point that following this path during a time $1$ with velocity $t\times v$. From a mathematician point of view: this is because of uniqueness of  the solutions of a given differential equation with same initial data.

Comment: Intuitively, it makes sense. However, I am interested in the proof though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose everything is well-defined: to be rigrous, we should restrict to appropriate little enough intervals for $s$ and $t$.

Fix $v\in T_pM$ and define $\gamma$ to be the unique geodesic in $(M,g)$ with initial data $(p,v)$. Define $\sigma_1(s) = \gamma(t\times s)$. Finally, define $\sigma_2$ to be the only solution to the geodesic equation with initial data $(p,t\times v)$. Then:

$$ \sigma_1(0)=\gamma(0) = p,~~{\sigma_1}'(0) = t \times \gamma'(0) = t\times v, $$

and
$$
\nabla_{{\sigma_1}'}{\sigma_1}' = 0
$$
Hence $\sigma_1 = \sigma _2$. Evaluate at $s = 1$.